# JFileChooser: Not able to select root dir

Tags: java, macos, swing, jfilechooser

I'm using a JFileChooser to let the user select a directory to perform a specific task on it (in fact, want to calculate the dir's recursive size). Unfortunately it seems that it is not possible to let the user choose the root dir on **OS X**: I can select the top dir in the drop-down (The Harddisk itself), but then the "Open" button gets disabled, as I didn't select a dir in the list (which I don't want, since those are already sub-dirs).

I use the following code to create the dialog (rather straight-forward, I thought):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
```

The result shows up as follows:

[screenshot (png, 78k): open dialog, but unable to choose top dir (Disk itself)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2191276/screen1.png)

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way doing it correct? It also don't help to use FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES mode, or a Save dialog, just the same...

Thanks
alex

Comment: Hey, I was able to do it using the same three lines mentioned above.. just that i did a showOpenDialog(null) as mentioned in the javadoc http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog%28java.awt.Component%29

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me: Still, the top item in the folder select combobox is the Mac's harddisk, but I cannnot _select_ it as actual selected dir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible with JFileChooser. You could use the awt FileDialog instead:

```
System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");
FileDialog d = new FileDialog(frame);
d.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Many thanks, that solves it, even if it breaks with the Swing components. Strange that this seems not able to be solved with swing...